# Anaconda does not start - attributeError: module 'six' has no attribute 'add_metaclass'

Tags: anaconda

I just installed Anaconda fresh on a new laptop. Installation was successful and everything seem in place. But Anaconda (or Spyder) does not start. I tried to use command prompt and type "anaconda-navigator" from "Scripts" folder, but it returns an error with "attributeError: module 'six' has no attribute 'add_metaclass'".

I tried "anaconda-navigator --reset" did not help. I tried "pip install --upgrade six", it did update 'six' but it did not solve the issue. "conda update anaconda-navigator" gives the same problem.

I have no admin rights on the laptop.
Anyone knows how to solve this? :(

[The error I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX13y.png)

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out.
It was a conflict with other Python instances installed on my laptop. All i needed to do was to "set PYTHONPATH=" and then everything worked like a charm :)